# I get "kotlinx/coroutines/io/ByteReadChannel" when I try to decode a json on server side with ktor and moshi

Tags: kotlin, server, ktor, moshi

In Application.kt I install moshi in Application.module

```
   install(ContentNegotiation){
        moshi()
    }
```

I declared a simple test calss and in the route I try to decode the test class:

```
data class Test(val testString: String)

fun Route.test() {
    post (TEST_ENDPOINT) {
        val testReceive = call.receive<Test>()
        call.respond(testReceive)
    }
```

The request is post with the following Headers and Body:

```
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Content-Type: application/json
Accept-Language: en-gb

{
  "testString": "dasdada"
}
```

Response headers:

```
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2020 11:55:58 GMT
Content-Length: 37
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Server: ktor-server-core/1.4.1 ktor-server-core/1.4.1
```

Response body:

```
kotlinx/coroutines/io/ByteReadChannel
```

Any suggestion or comment is appreciated.

Comment: The problem seems to be on the server side, as the server responded with a `500` error code. You're likely not printing the response body, but just the debug representation of the class (e.g. `toString()`). Hence it printed out the type, and not the content.

Comment: @KenVanHoeylandt, ok I understand, but even if I respond with a hardcoded string like this call.respond("test"), I get the same error. I believe the issue is from val testReceive = call.receive<Test>() but I don't understand where could be the problem.

Comment: Responding fails because the backend keeps failing. The problem is in the backend. Regarding the response being `kotlinx/coroutines/io/ByteReadChannel`: that's just you reading the response incorrectly in code. You can use `copyTo()` or `copyAndClose()` to convert it to a stream and then afterwards to a string.

Comment: The code runs on the backend and it receives the request form other clients. 
I moved to gson and it seems to work. I will post an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moshi 1.0.1 relies on some outdated Ktor API.
Consider either moving back to Ktor 1.3.2 or (better) use another JSON handler (there are several available out of the box: [Gson](https://ktor.io/docs/content-negotiation-gson.html), [Jackson](https://ktor.io/docs/content-negotiation-jackson.html) and [kotlinx.serialization](https://ktor.io/docs/serialization-converter.html))